# mintTo(...) of my Token-2022 - Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, token-2022, javascript

Here's a part of the code of minting my Token-2022 which I've deployed previously

```
//........................

console.log(
`\npayer: ${payer} $$ ${payer.publicKey}`,
`\nmint: ${mint}`,
`\nsourceTokenAccount: ${sourceTokenAccount}`,
`\nmintAuthority: ${mintAuthority} $$ ${mintAuthority.publicKey}`,
)


transactionSignature = await mintTo(
  connection,
  payer, // Transaction fee payer
  mint, // Mint Account address
  sourceTokenAccount, // Mint to
  mintAuthority, // Mint Authority address
  1_000_000_000, // Amount
  [], // Additional signers
  undefined, // Confirmation options
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
);

//Baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaam!!!!

console.log(
  "\nMint Tokens:",
  `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`,
);
```

Error:

```
payer: [object Object] $$ 6RzpGSb4cMRN6h46DVZ5czWRQsuPGCZdmhHdhUkAYQwU 
mint: EM1Y7YUqvH3Rjsi49wtxsi2R8vmzqaKbWY9PWK8JVBGY 
sourceTokenAccount: DvbiZQjwtBuEwAG2WAXaf6XoCYUN9zn7Ad7iRhfHVbGU 
mintAuthority: [object Object] $$ 4B8dYh439ziBUUWANjGLtAfYeZcwQ7RDEUkNY3qmHZPU

4101 |   }
4102 | }
4103 | 
4104 | class SendTransactionError extends Error {
4105 |   constructor(message, logs) {
4106 |     super(message);
           ^
error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid account data for instruction
      at new SendTransactionError (..../p1/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:4106:5)
      at ..../p1/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:8031:13
```

Payer has some SOL
https://solscan.io/account/4B8dYh439ziBUUWANjGLtAfYeZcwQ7RDEUkNY3qmHZPU?cluster=devnet

as `sourceTokenAccount` and `mintAuthority` do too. And you can check them out on solscan too.

Why the error? What's wrong with the arguments?

---

**update**

```
  const owner = Keypair.generate();

  sourceTokenAccount = await createAccount(
    connection,
    payer, // Payer to create Token Account
    mint, // Mint Account address
    owner.publicKey, // Token Account owner
    undefined, // Optional keypair, default to Associated Token Account
    undefined, // Confirmation options
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Token Extension Program ID
  );
```

At https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#setup there's no clue that it **has to be** a token account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that the `sourceTokenAccount` you are using here is not actually a token account, rather, it seems like a normal user account owned by system program.

When you are transferring tokens, you don't transfer tokens to a user's normal account, instead, the tokens are stored in a separate token account which belongs to that user's wallet address. In this case, you would need to create the source token account first.

After digging through transactions a bit, I can see that you did run the `CreateAssociatedToken` instruction, which created `A97rNqFV6PMyMwuKrJw1ysakYHRVHL49kMyQRf7TZN6b` as your token account, try putting this in your `sourceTokenAccount` variable, that should work.

Comment: it's not a token account even though its name suggests. Does it **have to** be one? I've updated my question

Comment: Yes it must be a token account. Notice in the documentation the `sourceAccount` is coming from `createAccount` function, which creates and returns a token account for us. You can see its source: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/4f1668510adef2117ee3c043bd26b79789e67c8d/token/js/src/actions/createAccount.ts#L22

Comment: But I've created `sourceTokenAccount`  the same way - by `createAccount(...)`

Comment: `....which creates and returns a token account for us. ` -- what is it that makes the function `createAccount(...)` create a **token** account rather than a normal one?

Comment: I provided the source code link for you for that exact reason because I knew you might have similar doubt haha! But main point of difference `createAssociatedTokenAccount` instruction is used underneath. Solana has native programs that allow specific native actions. System program is the native program which creates normal accounts, but SPL token program has an instruction that can create token account, which the `createAccount` function calls in client side.

Comment: Ok. But once again: in **my** code I'd **alerady** called `createAccount` priour to asking this question. So a token should've been created. As you can see. And yet it would then throw an error afterwards in `mintTo`.

Comment: Creating is not enough, you have to actually pass that token account's public key in your `sourceTokenAccount` parameter. I saw that you did create a token account and I mentioned it above, but in your code's `mintTo` function, you aren't actually using it. See the documentation again, it is calling the `createAccount` function, storing its returned public key in a variable, and passing the same variable in `sourceTokenAccount` parameter in `mintTo` function.